# Laravel routing on XAMPP with virtual hosts

Tags: php, apache, laravel-4

I'm learning laravel, and have been following this phpacademy tutorial: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gf6yNkYVCjs  I have virtual hosts setup with XAMPP Apache and that's all good.

In the routes.php file we have this:

```
Route::get('/', array('as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'HomeController@getIndex'));
Route::get('/login', array('as' => 'login', 'uses' => 'AuthController@getLogin'));
Route::post('/login', array('uses' => 'AuthController@postLogin'));
```

I type into my browser "tutorial" and I get the homepage as per the tutorial.

The problem is when I append login as in  "tutorial/login" then I get a 404 error, object not found.

The AuthController etc is all in place, but I suspect that I have a routing problem, I just can't figure out where.

**Update**:

If I just use the php inbuilt server "php artisan serve" then it all works fine. So It looks like more of an Apache config problem than a laravel problem.

Comment: *"...following this phpacademy tutorial"* ~ I'd say that's your first problem right there. Sounds like you're missing your Apache rewrite rules.

Comment: What's a better alternative?

Comment: I'd start with the official doco *Quickstart* guide ~ http://laravel.com/docs/quick. See the [Pretty URLs](http://laravel.com/docs/installation#pretty-urls) section regarding Apache `mod_rewrite` configuration

Comment: Good beginner books for Laravel 3/4: Code Happy & Code Bright from Dayle Rees (as e-book)